# Passing list of object to Web API using RestSharp Client

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, restsharp

I'm trying to send list of objects from MVC to WEBAPI using below methods. API is able to able receive the list from controller but, value of each item in the list is either empty/null on API side. 
Can anyone please help me to fix this?

**Controller Method:**

```
private List<FCM.Models.Facility> GetFacilityDetails()
{
    var url = "http://localhost:64664/";

    var facilies = new List<Facility>();

    facilies.Add( new Facility{ FCLT_ID = 100, FCLT_NM = "Facility 100" });
    facilies.Add( new Facility{ FCLT_ID = 200, FCLT_NM = "Facility 200" });
    facilies.Add( new Facility{ FCLT_ID = 300, FCLT_NM = "Facility 300" });

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(facilies);

    var _client = new RestClient(url);
    var request = new RestRequest("api/facility/details", Method.GET) { RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };

    facilies.ForEach(fclt =>
                    request.AddParameter("facilites", fclt, ParameterType.GetOrPost));

    var response = _client.Execute<List<FCM.Models.Facility>>(request);

    if (response.Data == null)
    {
        throw new Exception(response.ErrorMessage);
    }

    return response.Data;
}
```

**WebAPI method:**

```
[Route("api/facility/details")]
public IEnumerable<Facility> GetFullAddress([FromUri] IEnumerable<Facility> facilities)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176626/not-able-to-pass-list-of-object-to-web-api/39179375#39179375

Comment: Thank you for your solution! It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Like the comment suggested you maybe want to issue a `POST` request instead, but if you would like to send an array with a `GET`request you could do it like this (with `System.Net.Http.HttpClient`):

Add a `Format` method to you `Facility` class:

```
public class Facility
{
    public int FCLT_ID { get; set; }
    public string FCLT_NM { get; set; }

    public string Format(int index)
    {
        return $"[{index}].FCLT_ID={FCLT_ID}&[{index}].FCLT_NM={FCLT_NM}";
    }
}
```

Define a class which can format the array values:

```
public class FacilityList : List<Facility>
{
    public string Format()
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        for (var i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            builder.Append(this[i].Format(i));

            if(i != Count -1)
            {
                builder.Append("&");
            }
        }

        return builder.ToString();
    }
}
```

And then issue the request:

```
var client = new HttpClient()
{
    BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:64664/"),
    DefaultRequestHeaders = {Accept = {new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")}}
};

var facilities = new FacilityList
{
    new Facility {FCLT_ID = 100, FCLT_NM = "Facility 100"},
    new Facility {FCLT_ID = 200, FCLT_NM = "Facility 200"},
    new Facility {FCLT_ID = 300, FCLT_NM = "Facility 300"}
};

var format = facilities.Format();

var response = client.GetAsync("api/facility/details?" + format).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<Facility>>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult());
```

This will bind to your controller action:

```
[Route("api/facility/details")]
public IHttpActionResult Get([FromUri] IEnumerable<Facility> facilities)
{ 
    // Do stuff..
    return Ok(facilities);
}
```